# Неинициализированные переменные. Valgrind

Tags: c, строки, память, valgrind, выделение-памяти

Столкнулась с проблемой - при проверке кода валгриндом у меня выдаются следующие ошибки:

```
 Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==8698==    at 0x4C33DAC: strcmp (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8698==    by 0x108AED: main (in /home/rideks/CLionProjects/market_9.1.20/a.out)
==8698== 
==8698== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==8698==    at 0x108AF0: main (in /home/rideks/CLionProjects/market_9.1.20/a.out)
==8698==
```

На мой взгляд я все переменные инициализировала, вот код:

```
#include "library.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define ERROR printf("ERROR.\n");

typedef struct {

    char  cod [101];
    char count;


} CODS;




int main(void)
{
    CODS * cods = NULL;// in this arrray of structs we save our cods and theirs counts
    cods = (CODS *)malloc(sizeof(CODS)* 8);
    char * buf = NULL;
    size_t l = 0;
    int countCods = 0;
    int value = 0;
    int arrayCount = 0;


    while (1)
    {

        int in = getline(&buf, &l, stdin);
        if(in == EOF)
        {
                if(countCods == 0)
                {
                    ERROR
                    free(buf);
                    return 0;
                }
                break;

        }
        int lenBuf = (int)strlen(buf);
        if(lenBuf < 5 || lenBuf > 101 )
        {
            ERROR
            free(buf);
            return 0;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < lenBuf; i++)
        {
            if((buf[i] < '0' || buf[i] > '9' )&&(buf[i] != '\n'))
            {
                ERROR
                free(buf);
                return 0;
            }


        }
        ++ countCods;
        cods = (CODS *)realloc(cods, sizeof(CODS) * countCods);


        buf[lenBuf -1] = '\0';

         value = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < countCods; i++)
        {
                if(strcmp (buf,cods[i].cod) == 0) //if we have same strings
                {
                    ++cods[i].count;
                    value = 1;

                }
              //  else value = 0;
        }
        if(value == 0)
        {
            cods[countCods - 1].count = 1;
            strcpy(cods[countCods - 1].cod, buf);
            ++arrayCount;

        }




    }

    for(int i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++)
    {
        printf("--->%s<---\n",cods[i].cod);
    }




    if(cods)free (cods);
    if(buf)free(buf);


    return 0;

}
```

Если что, задача программы - считать список строк, проверить на то, и  являются ли цирами. Так же строка не смеет превышать 100 знаков и быть меньше 5. Затем, в последствии, проверяем коллчество повторений строк и записываем в count в структуре CODS. Добра.

Comment: В следующий раз компилируйте с ключом `-g` (отладочная информация), и valgrind будет поинформативнее.

Answer (score 4):

`valgrind` прав:

- Сначала добавляется новая неинициализированная строка в массив:

  ```
  ++ countCods;
  cods = (CODS *)realloc(cods, sizeof(CODS) * countCods);
  ```
- Затем проверяются все строки (включая пустую неинициализированную вновь добавленную)

  ```
  for(int i = 0; i < countCods; i++) {
          if(strcmp (buf,cods[i].cod) == 0) { //if we have same strings
              ++cods[i].count;
              value = 1;
          }
  }
  ```
- И только потом, если строка не была найдена ей присваивается значение:

  ```
  if(value == 0) {
      cods[countCods - 1].count = 1;
      strcpy(cods[countCods - 1].cod, buf);
      ++arrayCount;
  }
  ```

Comment: Поняла, большое Вам спасибо!!!!

Comment: не могли бы Вы помочь, пожалуйста? Не могу сообразить,  как это исправить

Comment: @DontBeSoAngry, просто перенеси выделение памяти из первого отрывка в третий под `if`... тогда `countCods` и `arrayCount` будут представлять собой одно и тоже — скорей всего одно из оных нужно будет убрать...